# Difference between "Require SSL" and "Require X509" SSL option on MariaDB

Tags: ssl, mariadb

I am learning enabling two way TLS set on MariaDB. For this it requires an user account with X509 SSL option. I read theory but still not clear about the difference. also, when should use which option.

Please help with this query.

### Edit

I have done one test where I found that with "Require SSL " option only "CA" certificate is required where with X509 , you need a client certificate along with ca certificate.

I am still not getting main login behind this.

Comment: Do you mean X509?

Comment: Yes , it'sX509 , i just updated questions

Answer (score 2):

For an account created with a `REQUIRE SSL` clause, the connection attempt fails if an encrypted connection cannot be established. For an account with no special encryption requirements, the attempt falls back to an unencrypted connection if an encrypted connection cannot be established.

For accounts created with a `REQUIRE X509` clause, clients must specify at least `--ssl-cert` and `--ssl-key`. In addition, `--ssl-ca` (or `--ssl-capath`) is recommended so that the public certificate provided by the server can be verified. For example:

```
mysql --ssl-ca=ca.pem \
      --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem \
      --ssl-key=client-key.pem
```

For accounts created with a `REQUIRE ISSUER` or `REQUIRE SUBJECT` clause, the encryption requirements are the same as for `REQUIRE X509`, but the certificate must match the issue or subject, respectively, specified in the account definition.

For additional information about the REQUIRE clause, see:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html

Answer (score 0):

If a user account has "Require SSL" set, that user can only connect over secured transport (no unencrypted port, if these are available, too) - but still can authenticate with username+password.

If a user account has "Requre X590" set, that user can only connect over secured transport - but a client certificate is needed for authentication.

Comment: What is  "Unencrypted port" ?

Comment: @kreya Here, "unencrypted port" means "plaintext connection" (MySQL uses the same TCP port for TLS and plaintext connections).

Answer (score 0):

As described by [MySql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-encrypted-connections.html):

> For an account created with a REQUIRE SSL clause, the connection attempt fails if an encrypted connection cannot be established. For an account with no special encryption requirements, the attempt falls back to an unencrypted connection if an encrypted connection cannot be established.

and

> For accounts created with a REQUIRE X509 clause, clients must specify at least --ssl-cert and --ssl-key. In addition, --ssl-ca (or --ssl-capath) is recommended so that the public certificate provided by the server can be verified.

and as [Igor Cicimov](https://icicimov.github.io/blog/database/MySQL-SSL-and-client-certificates-authentication/) mentioned:

> `REQUIRED X509` means that the client must have a valid certificate but that the exact certificate, issuer, and subject do not matter. The only requirement is that it should be possible to verify its signature with one of the CA certificates.

If you use `REQUIRE SSL` the clients does not required to present anything.
If you use `REQUIRE X509` the client have to present its own(?) cert and key in addition to user & pass to connect.

Both type forces encrypted communication but x509 mode is more strictly.